# extracting item with most common probability in python list

Tags: python, set

I have a list [[1, 2, 7], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 7], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]] and I need [1,2,3,7] as final result (this is kind of reverse engineering). One logic is to check intersections -

```
 while(i<dlistlen):
  j=i+1
  while(j<dlistlen):
   il = dlist1[i]
   jl = dlist1[j]

   tmp = list(set(il) & set(jl))
   print tmp 

  #print i,j
   j=j+1 
  i=i+1
```

this is giving me output :

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 7]
[1, 2, 7]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 7]
[]
```

Looks like I am close to getting [1,2,3,7] as my final answer, but can't figure out how. Please note, in the very first list (([[1, 2, 7], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 7], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]] )) there may be more items leading to one more final answer besides [1,2,3,4]. But as of now, I need to extract only [1,2,3,7] . 
Please note, this is not kind of homework, I am creating own clustering algorithm that fits my need.

Comment: Take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-a-list). It's not intersection but frequency distribution.

Comment: I don't understand how `[1,2,3,7]` is the "item with the most common probability"

Comment: Could you explain how you get from `[[1, 2, 7], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 7], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]]` to `[1,2,3,7]`.

Comment: @NPE realised that.. This question is strange, at least... Maybe all items that are included more than once?

Comment: @ppeterka: I don't know about strange, but it's certainly incomplete.

Comment: sorry for confusion, dlist1 = [[1, 2, 7], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 7], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]] and dlistlen= dlistlen = len(dlist1)
Hope, this clarifies How I got [[1, 2, 7], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 7], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]] to [1,2,3,7].

Comment: Thanks, as I said above it is a clustering algorithm and since it is under development, I know 1,2,3,7 is the right cluster. It is kind of reverse engineering.

Comment: this works perfectly given your description: `def return1237(): return [1,2,3,7]`

Comment: @AndrewJaffe thanks,but looking for a generalized solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.Counter) class to keep track of how often elements appear.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l =  [[1, 2, 7], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 7], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]]
>>> #use chain(*l) to flatten the lists into a single list
>>> c = Counter(chain(*l))
>>> print c
Counter({1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 3, 7: 3, 5: 1, 6: 1})
>>> #sort keys in order of descending frequency
>>> sortedValues = sorted(c.keys(), key=lambda x: c[x], reverse=True)
>>> #show the four most common values
>>> print sortedValues[:4]
[1, 2, 3, 7]
>>> #alternatively, show the values that appear in more than 50% of all lists
>>> print [value for value, freq in c.iteritems() if float(freq) / len(l) > 0.50]
[1, 2, 3, 7]
```

Comment: +1, straight. [:4] is pretty arbitrary but he didn't explain which is his criterion.

Comment: @Adrino, 4 is not my criteria, but now we can think of something like most frequently occurred etc. thanks. Now I will try on a larger data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to find the largest intersection of two list elements. This will do that:

```
from itertools import combinations

# convert all list elements to sets for speed
dlist = [set(x) for x in dlist]

intersections = (x & y for x, y in combinations(dlist, 2))
longest_intersection = max(intersections, key=len)
```