# How to sum duplicates values in list?

Tags: python

I have a simple list of strings:

```
1 test1
10 test1
2 test1
12 test2
87 test2
12 test1
75 test1
43 test1
```

How to get list of strings:

```
1+10+2 test1
12+87 test2
12+75+43 test1
```

?

Comment: And what have you tried to solve your own problem?

Comment: Were you looking to add all the `test1` values into one string?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-a-list

Comment: @aaronman: So how would you do use a list comprehension here? It is possible to collapse my solution into a list comprehension, but it is not going to be very readable, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters unfortunately I'm not really a python guy but I know list comps are a good tool from haskell

Comment: @aaronman: Yes, list comprehensions are a great tool, if applied in the right places. :-) I've added a list comprehension to my answer to produce only the sums.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your numbers per `test..` value:

```
from itertools import groupby

for key, group in groupby(list_of_strings, lambda k: k.split(None, 1)[-1]):
    # loop over `group` to see all strings that have the same last word.
    print '+'.join([s.split(None, 1)[0] for s in group]), key
```

`group` is an iterable that yields all *contiguous* strings that have the same second value (split on whitespace); your input has two `test1` groups that are contiguous, for example.

Demo:

```
>>> list_of_strings = '''\
... 1 test1
... 10 test1
... 2 test1
... 12 test2
... 87 test2
... 12 test1
... 75 test1
... 43 test1
... '''.splitlines()
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for key, group in groupby(list_of_strings, lambda k: k.split(None, 1)[-1]):
...     # loop over `group` to see all strings that have the same last word.
...     print '+'.join([s.split(None, 1)[0] for s in group]), key
... 
1+10+2 test1
12+87 test2
12+75+43 test1
```

or, if you wanted to actually sum the values as integers:

```
for key, group in groupby(list_of_strings, lambda k: k.split(None, 1)[-1]):
    print sum(int(s.split(None, 1)[0]) for s in group), key
```

which prints

```
13 test1
99 test2
130 test1
```

If you just need the sums, make it a list comprehension:

```
sums = [sum(int(s.split(None, 1)[0]) for s in g) for _, g in groupby(L, lambda k: k.split(None, 1)[-1])]
```