# Computation of Kullback-Leibler (KL) distance between text-documents using numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, distance

My goal is to compute the KL distance between the following text documents:

```
1)The boy is having a lad relationship
2)The boy is having a boy relationship
3)It is a lovely day in NY
```

I first of all vectorised the documents in order to easily apply numpy

```
1)[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
2)[1,2,1,1,1,2,1]
3)[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

I then applied the following code for computing KL distance between the texts:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from math import log

v=[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,1,1,2,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
c=v[0]
def kl(p, q):
    p = np.asarray(p, dtype=np.float)
    q = np.asarray(q, dtype=np.float)
    return np.sum(np.where(p != 0,(p-q) * np.log10(p / q), 0))
for x in v:
    KL=kl(x,c)
    print KL
```

Here is the result of the above code: `[0.0, 0.602059991328, 0.0]`.
Texts 1 and 3 are completely different, but the distance between them is 0, while texts 1 and 2, which are highly related has a distance of `0.602059991328`. This isn't accurate.

Does anyone has an idea of what I'm not doing right with regards to KL? Many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Well, v[0]==v[2], thus in the kl function p-q is 0, then the sum is 0. What do you mean by "vectorize the documents" ? Your vectors 1 and 3 are equals.

Comment: @J.Martinot_Lagarde thanks for your observation. to vectorize here means to have a frequency count of each word in a document, and to use the values to represent the document. The issue here is how to represent each document in such a way that the distance between two documents can be accurately computed using KL.

Answer (score 30):

Though I hate to add another answer, there are two points here. First, as Jaime pointed out in the comments, KL divergence (or distance - they are, according to the following documentation, the same) is designed to measure the difference between probability distributions. This means basically that what you pass to the function should be two array-likes, the elements of each of which sum to 1.

Second, scipy apparently does implement this, with a naming scheme more related to the field of information theory. The function is "entropy":

```
scipy.stats.entropy(pk, qk=None, base=None)
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html

From the docs:

> If qk is not None, then compute a relative entropy (also known as
>   Kullback-Leibler divergence or Kullback-Leibler distance) S = sum(pk *
>   log(pk / qk), axis=0).

The bonus of this function as well is that it will normalize the vectors you pass it if they do not sum to 1 (though this means you have to be careful with the arrays you pass - ie, how they are constructed from data).

Hope this helps, and at least a library provides it so don't have to code your own.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of googling to undersand the KL concept, I think that your problem is due to the vectorization : you're comparing the number of appearance of different words. You should either link your column indice to one word, or use a dictionnary:

```
#  The boy is having a lad relationship It lovely day in NY
1)[1   1   1  1      1 1   1            0  0      0   0  0]
2)[1   2   1  1      1 0   1            0  0      0   0  0]
3)[0   0   1  0      1 0   0            1  1      1   1  1]
```

Then you can use your kl function.

To automatically vectorize to a dictionnary, see [How to count the frequency of the elements in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-a-list) (`collections.Counter` is exactly what you need). Then you can loop over the union of the keys of the dictionaries to compute the KL distance.

Comment: That won't work... According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition): "The K–L divergence is only defined if P and Q both sum to 1 and if Q(i)=0 implies P(i)=0." Not sure how to go about it, though.

Comment: Right. The most useful article I found was http://staff.science.uva.nl/~tsagias/?p=185. They compute on the intersection of the vocabulary instead of the union, and add a "workaroud" when the vocabularies are too different. There's even code at the end. Anyway the problem lies in the "vectorisation" part here.

Comment: Thanks @J.Martinot-Lagarde, I'll take a look at the article.

Comment: Another approach to deal with differences in vocab between docs is to add a small probability/frequency to each word, so none have probability zero. This is fairly standard in machine learning, and probably a better idea than ignoring them (eg: if two docs have one word in common, but many different, they are considered identical when you consider the intersection of the vocab!)

Comment: @J.Martinot-Lagarde Actually, if you read on in the paper linked, you'll see that they don't use the intersection, but do what I just described..

Comment: link is deadnow, I found an cahed ver https://web.archive.org/web/20130508191111/http://staff.science.uva.nl/~tsagias/?p=185

Answer (score 0):

A potential issue might be in your NP definition of KL. Read the wikipedia page for formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence

Note that you multiply (p-q) by the log result. In accordance with the KL formula, this should only be p:

```
 return np.sum(np.where(p != 0,(p) * np.log10(p / q), 0))
```

That may help...

Comment: the formula you have there is for non-symmetric KL divergence. Just have a look at symmetric KL divergence, you  will understand me better.

Comment: I understand the need for symmetric KL, but I believe what you're doing won't give you it. For a version, check out the Jensen-Shannon divergence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence

Comment: I already have Jensen-Shannon devergence in place. I even answered a question on JS divergence on stack overflow. Besides JS divergence, there are other symmetrized version of KL divergence.