# Python:Fast/efficient implementation of the Kullback Leibler divergence for multiple distributions calculation

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, statistics, histogram

I have the following problem: I have a matrix of, say 20K discrete distributions (histograms) and I need to calculate the KL divergence (KLD) between each of these pairs. The trivial way to do that is by using two for loops and calculating KLD between each two distributions via the standard KLD calculation. It takes time. Lots of time. I wonder of there is a some kind of matrix/array based calculation of the above. Surely I am not the first one who encounters this problem. Unfortunately I am new at python. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
A.

Comment: what did you do so far? do you have some code to look at?

Comment: what does a single distribution look like - ie, 20 floating-point values which sum to 1.0?

Answer (score 7):

I found [Computation of Kullback-Leibler (KL) distance between text-documents using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380037/computation-of-kullback-leibler-kl-distance-between-text-documents-using-numpy#24639993) which notes that SciPy has an implementation of KLD as

```
scipy.stats.entropy(pk, qk=None, base=None)
```

and documentation can be found at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html ; this should make the calculation itself faster.

Alternatively, [an implementation in numpy](https://gist.github.com/larsmans/3104581):

```
import numpy as np
 
def kl(p, q):
    """Kullback-Leibler divergence D(P || Q) for discrete distributions
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    p, q : array-like, dtype=float, shape=n
    Discrete probability distributions.
    """
    p = np.asarray(p, dtype=np.float)
    q = np.asarray(q, dtype=np.float)
    
    return np.sum(np.where(p != 0, p * np.log(p / q), 0))
```

Do note that converting data to and from numpy arrays is relatively slow; I do not know if it would be better to keep a list of 20k 1D numpy arrays (could be very memory-intensive), or keep a single 2D numpy array and operate on slices.

Answer (score 0):

itertools is a powerful tool for all kind of permutations, etc. between different entities. Among other things, it does double "for" loops via the product function:

```
from itertools import product
KL = [kl(hist_mat[:,i],hist_mat[:,j]) for i,j in product( range(0,K), range(0,K) )]
```

*K* being the number of histograms to compare in a pairwise manner,
*hist_mat*  containing the histograms in each of it's columns.
*kl*  = your implementation of choice for the kullback leibler divergence

The only minus is that for large data-sets it still works slow.

Cheers,
A.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
def kullback_leibler_divergence(X):

    """
    Finds the pairwise Kullback-Leibler divergence
    matrix between all rows in X.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array_like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
        Array of probability data. Each row must sum to 1.

    Returns
    -------
    D : ndarray, shape (n_samples, n_samples)
        The Kullback-Leibler divergence matrix. A pairwise matrix D such that D_{i, j}
        is the divergence between the ith and jth vectors of the given matrix X.

    Notes
    -----
    Based on code from Gordon J. Berman et al.
    (https://github.com/gordonberman/MotionMapper)

    References:
    -----------
    Berman, G. J., Choi, D. M., Bialek, W., & Shaevitz, J. W. (2014). 
    Mapping the stereotyped behaviour of freely moving fruit flies. 
    Journal of The Royal Society Interface, 11(99), 20140672.
    """

    X_log = np.log(X)
    X_log[np.isinf(X_log) | np.isnan(X_log)] = 0

    entropies = -np.sum(X * X_log, axis=1)

    D = np.matmul(-X, X_log.T)
    D = D - entropies
    D = D / np.log(2)
    D *= (1 - np.eye(D.shape[0]))

    return D
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try numba

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def kld(p, q):
    """
    Epsilon is used here to avoid infinity result
    """
    epsilon = 1e-8
    
    p = p+epsilon
    q = q+epsilon

    divergence = np.sum(p*np.log(p/q))
    return divergence
```