# How can I make histogram from word length in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to make a histogram, that shows the word length frequency from a poem.
I've got the frequency, but I can't represent it in a histogram.
This is my code:

```
full = "Ej mi a kő! tyúkanyó, kend A szobában lakik itt bent? Lám, csak jó az isten, jót ád, Hogy fölvitte a kend dolgát!  Itt szaladgál föl és alá, Még a ládára is fölszáll, Eszébe jut, kotkodákol, S nem verik ki a szobábol. Dehogy verik, dehogy verik! Mint a galambot etetik, Válogat a kendermagban, A kiskirály sem él jobban. Ezért aztán, tyúkanyó, hát Jól megbecsűlje kend magát, Iparkodjék, ne legyen ám Tojás szűkében az anyám. – Morzsa kutyánk, hegyezd füled, Hadd beszélek mostan veled, Régi cseléd vagy a háznál, Mindig emberűl szolgáltál, Ezután is jó légy, Morzsa, Kedvet ne kapj a tyúkhusra, Élj a tyúkkal barátságba’... Anyám egyetlen jószága."
vs = full.translate(string.punctuation)
vers =  vs.lower().split()
c=[len(i) for i in vers] # gives [3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 6, 4, 4, 3, 5]
counts=[0]*max(c)      # gives [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range(len(c)):
  counts[c[i]-1]+=1    # adds 1 to each index of c[i] (we subtract 1 because of 0-based indices)
print(counts)

plt.hist(counts, 14)
```

What did I do wrong? The X and Y axis are inverted, it shows the word length opposive. :(
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the necessary imports, like `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`?

Comment: Maybe the solution is in [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)

Comment: `plt.hist` does the counting for you. Just do `plt.hist([len(i) for i in vers], 14)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for. I referred to this - ([Using Counter() in Python to build histogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198920/using-counter-in-python-to-build-histogram/19199002#19199002))

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

full = "Ej mi a kő! tyúkanyó, kend A szobában lakik itt bent? Lám, csak jó az isten, jót ád, Hogy fölvitte a kend dolgát!  Itt szaladgál föl és alá, Még a ládára is fölszáll, Eszébe jut, kotkodákol, S nem verik ki a szobábol. Dehogy verik, dehogy verik! Mint a galambot etetik, Válogat a kendermagban, A kiskirály sem él jobban. Ezért aztán, tyúkanyó, hát Jól megbecsűlje kend magát, Iparkodjék, ne legyen ám Tojás szűkében az anyám. – Morzsa kutyánk, hegyezd füled, Hadd beszélek mostan veled, Régi cseléd vagy a háznál, Mindig emberűl szolgáltál, Ezután is jó légy, Morzsa, Kedvet ne kapj a tyúkhusra, Élj a tyúkkal barátságba’... Anyám egyetlen jószága."
xxx=list(full)
labels, values = zip(*Counter(xxx).items())

indexes = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 1

plt.bar(indexes, values, width)
plt.xticks(indexes + width * 0.5, labels)
plt.show()
```