# Plot Counter as scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, counter

Ive got a Counter which currently I print out a long list of each word and its corresponding frequency of occurrence using the following:

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = []
with open('csv.csv') as f:
    data = [word for row in csv.reader(f) for word in row[1].lower().split()]
counts = Counter(data)

for value, count in counts.most_common():
    print(value, count)
```

I would like to view the data instead in either a scatter plot or bar chart format. The issue I have with the solution [Using Counter() in Python to build histogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198920/using-counter-in-python-to-build-histogram) is that it throws an error about not all my strings being unicode and just shows one bar of maximum length.

Comment: Too broad question :o You could do this in so many ways. Try looking at gnuplot, highcharts, plotly, etc.

Comment: What is input, script and error message in this case? Which part doesn't like the string and why? Without this information, you will only get generic answers.