# How to plot collections.Counter histogram using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, collections

How to plot histogram of following Counter object?:

```
w = collections.Counter()
l = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
for o in l:
    w[o]+=1
```

Comment: The constructor for `Counter` can take a list directly and give you the count, so your code can be replaced with `collections.Counter(['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'])`. And have you tried [matplotlib.pyplot.hist](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Counter() in Python to build histogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198920/using-counter-in-python-to-build-histogram)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Looking at your data and attempt, I guess you want a bar plot instead of a histogram. Histogram is used to plot a distribution but that is not what you have. You can simply use the `keys` and `values` as the arguments of `plt.bar`. This way, the keys will be automatically taken as the x-axis tick-labels.

```
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
l = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
w = collections.Counter(l)
plt.bar(w.keys(), w.values())
```

[image]

Comment: this solution causes `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_keys'`

Comment: @Leopoldo: Can you please tell me what version of python you are using?

Comment: Can you try using `plt.bar(list(w.keys()), list(w.values()))`

Comment: Python 3.6.4. With `list` casting works fine, thank you!

Comment: @Sheldore how did you get such a nice looking bar plot? Did you have to tinker with the normal matplotlib styles?

Comment: Aha, `with plt.style.context('fivethirtyeight'):`

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing this is what you want to do? You'd just have to add xtick labels(see matplotlib documentation)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import collections

l = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']

count = collections.Counter(l)
print(count)

plt.bar(range(len(count)), count.values())
plt.show()
```