# Keras - flow_from_directory: How to get number of samples in each category?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there a way in Keras how to get count of images within each category when using ImageDataGenerator? Let's say I have train folder with 3 subfolders (classes) and each containing some number of images.

```
imagedatagen = ImageDataGenerator(...)    

imageflow = imagedatagen.flow_from_directory(
  source_dir, 
  class_mode='categorical', ...)
```

I can get class mapping or number of all samples with following commands:

```
class_dict = imageflow.class_indices # returns ie. {'aligator': 0, 'cat': 1, 'dog': 2}
sample_count = imageflow.samples # returns sum of all samples, not divided into categories
```

But how may I get info, that category 0 contains 1000 pictures, category 1 contains 1500 pictures and category 2 all the rest? I know that I can iterate all files with help of `os` module, but would like to know if there is some other way and I could not find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as my knowledge there is no built-in approach to this.

You can try with [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module.

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(imageflow.classes)

print(counter.items()) # dict_items([(0, 1648), (1, 3614)])
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I need (and better than `os`)

Comment: how i can plot it as bar graph?

Comment: @alex3465 you can use can find the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198920/using-counter-in-python-to-build-histogram