# can you help ,e with the list of python?

Tags: python, list, concurrency, sequence, powerschool

Hi I'm a university student and I have to do a program.
given a list of letters I have to say which is the length of the longest sequence.
for example if I have the following list ["C", "A", "G", "G", "G", "T", "A", "C", "A", "A",] the solution that I have to find is the following 3, "G" as the G has been repeated 3 times in a row. could someone help me? thank you

i need for university

Comment: What you actually "need" is to figure out how to do this on your own.  That's what University is for.

Comment: Show your solution attempts. What are the problems?

Comment: Have you tried thinking about how you are going to solve it? Take a piece of paper and scribble down the steps that you would do to solve this problem. Then translate that to code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding consecutively repeating strings in Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438491/finding-consecutively-repeating-strings-in-python-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`

Link to doc : [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
import itertools

lst = ["C", "A", "G", "G", "G", "T", "A", "C", "A", "A"]
result = []
for item, group in itertools.groupby(lst):
    count = sum(1 for _ in group)
    result.append((item,count),)

print(result)
#[('C', 1), ('A', 1), ('G', 3), ('T', 1), ('A', 1), ('C', 1), ('A', 2)]

#For maximum you can do:

m=max(result,key=lambda x:x[1])
#('G', 3)

m[0]
#'G'
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use a [collection.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as following:

```
from collections import Counter

my_list = ["C", "A", "G", "G", "G", "T", "A", "C", "A", "A"]

counter = Counter(my_list)
```

Now you could print counter to see the ordered list:

```
print(counter)
```

And the result will be:

```
Counter({'A': 4, 'G': 3, 'C': 2, 'T': 1})
```

Or you can also query a specific key to know the get the count:

```
print(counter['G'])
```

Comment: This does not account for repetitions as I understood it. Say, one G is out of the sequence, this would still count all occurrences of G, not if they are in their order e.g. `["C", "A", "G", "G", "G", "T", "A", "C", "A", "A","G"]`

Comment: It's best not to answer obvious assignment questions where the poster has obviously not even tried to solve it themselves.

Comment: You are both right!
@NelsonGon, I read the question too fast. My mistake.

Comment: @joanis, I will try not to answer any more questions when it is so obvious that there has not been enough effort.
Thanks both