# How to check if there is a repeated value in a list and get that value

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop

How can I find the repeated value in a list? 
There will always be only one repeated value

for example:

```
numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,3]
```

I need to get the value 3

This is what I was trying but it is sometimes printing the value of the same list 2 times.

```
endLoop=False
    for n1 in range(0,len(numbers)):
        for n2 in range(1,len(numbers)):
            if numbers[n1]==numbers[n2]:
                print numbers
                print numbers[n1]
                endLoop=True
        if endLoop:
            break
```

Comment: What should happen if there is more than one repeated value? No repeated values? Does it matter if values are repeated more often than others?

Comment: There will always be only 1 repeated value. Thanks for the comment, editing the post now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-a-list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that  `n1 != n2`

because your program will check `numbers[1] == numbers[1]` and print the value at the position `1`, even there is only one vaulue equal to `numbers[1]`

so the code will look like:

```
for n1 in range(0,len(numbers)):
    for n2 in range(1,len(numbers)):
        if numbers[n1]==numbers[n2] and n1 != n2:
            print numbers
            print numbers[n1]
            endLoop=True
    if endLoop:
        break
```

Answer (score 7):

Keep track of numbers you have seen with a [`set()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), the first number that is already in the set is repeated:

```
def find_repeat(numbers):
    seen = set()
    for num in numbers:
        if num in seen:
            return num
        seen.add(num)
```

This is an efficient method to find the *first* repeated value, as it won't have to look at the rest of the numbers once it finds it.

Comment: What exactly does set() do? and also the last line.

Comment: @FUtoFarai creates an empty set then adds the number to the set if it meets the condition

Comment: @FutoFarai: a set contains *unique* values, and testing for membership is very efficient. `seen.add()` adds a value to the set, `num in seen` tests if a value is already in the set.

Comment: this is very inefficient, because operations related to the `set` takes a lot of the time.

Comment: @cupidon4uk: no, they do **not** take a lot of time. Adding to a set, as well as membership tests, are O(1) constant time operations, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity. Do you have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right, sorry. This way, it is much better approach than O(n*n) :)

Comment: @cupidon4uk: exactly; the OP approach is a O(N^2) approach, this is a O(N) approach, both worst case.

Comment: If you were doing an interview or test, this would be the only acceptable answer.

Answer (score 6):

there is a simpler method to do so. using .count() keyword.
you can do something like this

```
for n in numbers:
    if numbers.count(n)>1:
        print("Repeated number: ",n)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using numpy:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,3]
counts = np.bincount( numbers )
np.where([ counts > 1 ])[1]
```

... Will get you array([3])

Comment: This does require a full scan again. It can be solved with less work because the OP only needs the *first* repeated number.

Comment: You are quite right.  This solution work well only if the array is reasonably short and/or speed is not a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner.

```
set([x for x in _list if _list.count(x) > 1])
```

Comment: This is *very* inefficient; each `test.count()` call does a full scan of the list to count the elements. You are also repeating the count for any repeated element.

Answer (score 0):

```
g=int(input("how many digits?"))
n=int(input("enter a number"))
c=0
k=0
k=n
for i in range(0,g):
    While  (n!=0):
               r=n%10
               n=n//10
               r1=n%10
               If (r==r1):
                               c=c+1
 if (c>0):
     print("reparation is there")
 else:
     print("no repeatation .....")
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Answer (score 0):

A variant to Lukeclh s' answer

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,3]
counts = np.bincount( numbers )
np.where( counts > 1 )[0]
```

will give the same result