# python regular expression count and print

Tags: python, regex

I have following file text.text:-

08-JUN-2013 05:04:02
08-JUN-2013 05:04:02
08-JUN-2013 05:04:02
08-JUN-2013 05:04:03
08-JUN-2013 05:04:03
08-JUN-2013 05:05:23
08-JUN-2013 05:05:23
08-JUN-2013 05:05:23
08-JUN-2013 05:05:23

I want to print something like this using Python:-

08-JUN-2013 05:04:02 ------3
08-JUN-2013 05:04:03-------2
08-JUN-2013 05:05:23-------4

Here is what i did on this and i am newbie here :-

> "
>   import re
>   pattern = re.compile("\d+-\w+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+")
>   open_file=open('mytest.txt')
>    for line in open_file:
>      four_letter_words = pattern.findall(line)
>      fp_len            = len(pattern.findall(line))
>        for word in four_letter_words:
>          print four_letter_words ,  fp_len
>   "

Comment: This has nothing to do with regular expressions. Read up on dictionaries instead (or also, because you'll need regexes someday :-) ).

Comment: You should try to have the ***3** what's* in your question: **What** do you want to do? **What** have you tried? **What** is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for answer on this . As i am learning Python and newbie  i will read dictionaries .

Answer (score 1):

No need for `regex`.
you can use *counter* from *collections* modul, as described here [SO already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2162045/5601069)

Comment: Thanks I tried this its not working . As they are dates and i want to group by Seconds and then print the result.

Comment: have you used sort method? I suppose you have used counter, then result is dictionary, so try `sorted(result)`