# Write a program that lets the user enter a string and displays the character that appears most frequently in the string

Tags: python, string, lines

I am currently working on python, and I do not understand this much. I am looking for help with this question, before the dictionaries. This question is to be completed without any dictionaries. The problem is I do not know much about the max function.

So Far I have:

```
AlphaCount = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

for ch in text: 
   ch = ch.upper()
   index=Alpha.find(ch)

   if index >-1:
       AlphaCount[index] = AlphaCount[index]+1
```

Comment: And the problem with this code is? (apart from wrong capitalisation on `if`)

Comment: You'd better use a dictionary instead ...

Comment: @MMF- Looks like this (homework?) question "is to be completed without any dictionaries."

Comment: The key question is whether or not joint-highest frequency values need to be considered, if not then `max(set(text), key=text.count)`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-a-list

Comment: If you really want to do it without dictionary, then you should start by sorting the text `sorted(text.upper())` and then iterate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Counter

```
from collections import Counter
foo = 'wubalubadubdub'
Counter(list(foo))
```

To get the most frequent letter

```
Counter(list(foo)).most_common(1)
```

Comment: No need to explicitly cast to list for the `most_common` call. Also technically `Counter` is a `dict` sub-class, so contradicts the OP's requirement

Comment: If dictionaries are not allowed, I highly doubt that `Counter` would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` which will get only unique characters from the input. Then iterate over them and count how many times it occurs in the input with `count`. If it occurs more often then the max and `isalpha` (not a space) then set max to the count.

```
text='This is a test of tons of tall tales'
un=set(text.upper())
max=0
fav=''

for u in un:
    c=text.upper().count(u)
    if c>max and u.isalpha():
        max=c
        fav=u
print(fav) # T
print(max) # 6
```

**EDIT**

To do this from your code: fix capitalization(for, if) and then find and print/return the most common letter. Also `AlphaCount` has an extra 0, you only need 26.

```
text='This is a test of tons of tall talez'
AlphaCount=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Alpha='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

for ch in text: 
    ch= ch.upper()
    index=Alpha.find(ch)

    if index >-1:
        AlphaCount[index]+=1
print(AlphaCount) # the count of characters
print(max(AlphaCount)) # max value in list
print(AlphaCount.index(max(AlphaCount))) # index of max value
print(Alpha[AlphaCount.index(max(AlphaCount))]) # letter that occurs most frequently
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():

    string = input('Enter a sentence: ')

    strings=string.lower()

    counter = 0
    total_counter = 0

    most_frequent_character = ""

    for ch in strings:
        for str in strings:
            if str == ch:

                counter += 1
        if counter > total_counter:
            total_counter = counter
            most_frequent_character = ch
        counter = 0

    print("The most frequent character is", most_frequent_character, "and it appears", total_counter, "times.")

main()
```