# Python: Counting String frequency list type

Tags: python

I am using python to count the frequency of list **WITHOUT** using any collection just solely my own python basics functions.
My code is:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b','a', 'a','b','b', 'a','a','c']

def counting(): 
#Please help
```

Print out put should be like

```
a: 5
b: 3
c: 1
```

Please help thank you.

Comment: That doesn't count as "codes".

Comment: what is the content of the function counting()?

Comment: @mrCarnivore OH just I dont know how to make function of it. I will leave it blank

Comment: Take look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9744274/6900838)

Answer (score 1):

Use `count` , an inbuilt `list` function.

```
def counting(my_list):
      return { x:my_list.count(x) for x in my_list }
```

Just call it :

```
>>> counting(my_list)
=> {'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 1}

#print it as per requirement
>>> for k,v in counting(my_list).items(): 
        print(k,':',v) 

a : 5
b : 3
c : 1
```

#driver value :

```
IN : my_list = ['a', 'b','a', 'a','b','b', 'a','a','c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary to hold the results and check if the key exists increment the value, otherwise set the value of 1 (first occurrence).

```
my_list = ['a', 'b','a', 'a','b','b', 'a','a','c']

def counting(my_list):
  counted = {}
  for item in my_list:
    if item in counted:
      counted[item] += 1
    else:
      counted[item] = 1

  return counted

print(counting(my_list))
```