# How do you count the number of same entities in a list?

Tags: python

For example

```
MyList=[a,a,a,c,c,a,d,d,d,b]
```

Returns

```
[4,2,3,1]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please put the alphabets in quotes, like `'a'` as opposed to `a`, else it won't work.

Comment: You can look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-a-list/2162045

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
MyList=['a','a','a','c','c','a','d','d','d','b']
Counter(MyList).values() # Counts's the frequency of each element
    [4, 2, 1, 3]
Counter(MyList).keys()  # The corresponding elements
    ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
```

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item this is kinda slow because it checks the type of the elements every time. It'd be better another approach if you don't need type checking

Answer (score 0):

just do it with dictionary :

```
counter_dict = {}
for elem in MyList:
    if elem in counter_dict.keys():
         counter_dict[elem] += 1
    else :
         counter_dict[elem] = 1
```

at the end you have a dictionary with `key` with key , which is the element in the list , and `value` which is the number of appearances.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only a list:

```
# Your list
l1 = [1,1,2,3,1,2]
# Set will give you each element from l1 without duplicates
l2 = set(l1)
# Let`s see how set look
#print(l2)
# Create new empty list
l3 = []
# Use for loop to find count of each element from set and store that in l3
for i in l2:
   k = l1.count(i)
   l3.append(k)
# Check how l3 now looks like
print(l3)
```

Return:

```
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should change your list elements to a **string** type:

```
my_list = ['a','a','a','c','c','a','d','d','d','b']
```

Because `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` without quote(`'`) don't represent any type,so then you'll get error.

Try to use python dictionary, as follows:

```
result ={}
for each in my_list:
    result.setdefault(each, 0) 
    result[each] += 1
print result.values()
```

Then this would be the output:

```
[4,2,3,1]
```

Answer (score -1):

A first try would be doing this:

```
occurrencies = {n:a.count(n) for n in set(a)}
```

This returns a dictionary which has the element as key, and its occurrences as value. I use `set` to avoid counting elements more than once.

This is not a one-pass approach and it has quadratic complexity in time, hence this could be really slow.

Here's a way you could do to get the same result with one pass, linear complexity:

```
def count_occurrencies(inputArray):
    result = {}
    for element in inputArray:
        if element not in result:
            result[element] = 1
        else:
            result[element] += 1
    return result
```

Comment: *This is not a one-pass approach* — worse, this is actually quadratic.

Comment: The one-liner is quadratic. The `count_occurrencies` is linear. Dictionary `result` access is like a hash table, hence access is O(1), and it cycles through the `inputArray` only once

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your comment, I'm gonna edit to be more specific, thanks for pointing that out