# Calculate the frequency of all the combination of 2 words in Python

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, frequency, word-count

I have a paragraph of text. I want to calculate all the possible combination of 2 words (2 words have to be next to each other)
For example:

```
"I have 2 laptops, I have 2 chargers"
```

The result should be:

```
"I have": 2
"have 2": 2
"2 laptops": 1
"Laptops, I": (Dont count)
"2 chargers": 1
```

I tried Regex but the thing is that it doesnt count a string twice

I used: `\b[a-z]{1,20}\b \b[a-z]{1,20}\b`

Text: `cold chain, energy storage device, industrial cooling system`

It works almost but it doesn't include words such as "storage device", `cooling system` because it already takes `energy storage` and `industrial cooling`

Appreciate your advice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python) and [How to count the frequency of the elements in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` to get groups of every two words and then use `Counter` to get the frequency

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> text = "I have 2 laptops, I have 2 chargers"
>>> words = text.split()

>>> d = {' '.join(words):n for words,n in Counter(zip(words, words[1:])).items() if not  words[0][-1]==(',')}
>>> print (d)
{'I have': 2, 'have 2': 2, '2 laptops,': 1, '2 chargers': 1}

>>> import json
>>> print (json.dumps(d, indent=4))
{
    "I have": 2,
    "have 2": 2,
    "2 I": 1,
    "2 chargers": 1
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.  I tried your approach. it works but how could we exclude those "laptops, I"  which contain comma "," ? I have to go through thounsand of lines to make a statistic of 2-words combination and it's important to exclude those with comma in between

Comment: By the way, a sample text from my work is like : " old chain, energy storage device, industrial cooling system, industrial iot, intelligent storage, managed service platform provider, power management, refrigerant, thermal energy storage" . So if i used your approach, a lot of 2-word phrases with comma in bettwen or in word-end will apear. which i want to exclude those result

Comment: I have updated the answer to exclude words with comma