# How to return True and false if duplicate value exists

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
list = ["A", "A", "B", "A", "C"]
```

and a `for` and `if` statement combined:

```
for x in list:
    if "A" in x:
        print("true")
```

Output for the above code:

```
true
true
```

Next, I am figuring out how to tell me there is duplicates of `"A"` in list and return me value of `True`

Here is what i have tried:

```
for x in list:
    if any(x == "A" in x):
        return True
```

but an error shows up:
`SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

tried this too:

```
 for x in list:
    if any(x == "A" in x):
    return True
SyntaxError: expected an indented block
```

my desired output would be:

`True`
because duplicates of `"A"` exists

Comment: `return` statements are to be used in functions. And in your second attempt, the error is quite selfexplanatory

Comment: Python needs indented code in order to work. You just have to shift a couple of spaces to the right the code "return True", and your code will work. In addition, {return} needs to be part of a function.

Comment: @yatu could you help me with a provided example please?

Comment: code works, but does not return `True`.. do i need to insert `print("true")?

Comment: Why did you switch from `print('true')` to `return True`?

Comment: @quamrana because if my list had more `"A"` it would print me multiple `"true"` values, whereas i just need just the 1 True

Comment: add a `break` after printing true once. So, `for x in list:
    if any(x == "A" in x):
        print True break`

Comment: @Trollsors i like that idea. but does depend on what you're trying to achieve.. thanks

Comment: btw don't use `list` as a variable name. Try `lst` or `lis` ...

Comment: @quamrana how come?

Comment: `list` is the name of the list type and if you use it as a variable name you cannot then convert something to a list using `list(something)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

# hold in a 'dictionary' style something like: {'A':2, 'B':1, 'C':2}
c = Counter(['A','A','B', 'C', 'C'])

# check if 'A' appears more than 1 time. In case there is no 'A' in 
# original list, put '0' as default. 
c.get('A', 0) > 1 # 

>> True
```

Comment: Can that be changed to variable `list`? instead of using list inside the counter

Answer (score 1):

`return` is used to return a value from function outside function block it wont work.

For a given list `[1,2,3,4,1,1,3]` `.count(element)` will return number of occurrences if it is greater than 1 you cam be sure that is has duplicates

You can try like this

```
for x in list:
    if "A" in x:
        print("true")
        print(list.count("A")) #count will return more that 1 if there are duplicates
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the trick:

```py
def duplicate(mylist):
    for item in mylist:
        if mylist.count(item) > 1:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Return only works inside of a function.

Try this:

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-a-list/2162045)

```
def test(_list):
        d = {x:_list.count(x) for x in _list}
        result = [x for x in d.values()]
        if any(i > 1 for i in d.values()): 
            return True
        else: return False

_list = ["A", "A", "B", "A", "C"]  
print( test(_list) )
```