# How to count the occurance of all elements of list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have to write all the elements separately along with their count.
[It's the program i have made. It is counting correctly but not giving required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ujrp.png)

[The output is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SByvh.png)
[I want output to be like this. All digits showing individual complete count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYPMH.png)

Comment: In StackOverflow we don't put images of code, could you please paste your code here and mark it as `code` so that the syntax highlighter does its job.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the frequency of the elements in an unordered list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-an-unordered-list)

Answer (score 2):

You can count the number of occurrence of a special element with `count()` method:

```py
grades = ['b', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b']
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']

print(list(map(lambda letter: {letter: grades.count(letter)}, letters)))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'a': 4}, {'b': 4}, {'c': 2}, {'d': 2}, {'f': 1}]
```

---

If you want to do this without using `letters`. you can do this:

```py
grades = ['b', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b']

print(list(map(lambda letter: {letter: grades.count(letter)}, set(grades))))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'f': 1}, {'b': 4}, {'c': 2}, {'d': 2}, {'a': 4}]
```

---

For your expected output:

```py
grades = ['b', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b']

occurrence = map(lambda letter: (letter, grades.count(letter)), set(grades))

for item in occurrence:
    print(f"{item[0]}={item[1]}")
```

**Output:**

```
c=2
b=4
d=2
f=1
a=4
```

---

#### Update

You can use `defaultdict()` to count the occurrence of each element:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

grades = ['b', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b']
occurrence = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

for character in grades:
    occurrence[character] += 1

for key, value in occurrence.items():
    print(f"{key}={value}")
```

**Output:**

```
b=4
f=1
c=2
a=4
d=2
```

Comment: How to do it without using predefined function like count/

Comment: You can use ``defaultdict`` to count the occurrence of each element. I updated the answer.