# Inside python code read file directly and apply module regex

Tags: python, regex, printing, module

I have the following python-regex `read.py` file modified below from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59562329/10824251).
In the same directory I have another text file called 1.txt.

**read.py**

```
import re
with open ("1.txt", "r") as text:
    data = text.read()
print( re.sub(r"(.)\1*", lambda x: "{}{}".format( x.group(1), len(x.group())),  text) )
```

**1.txt**

```
UUBBBRRLLLBBBDDD
```

I am trying to read the contents of `1.txt` into `text` in the `read.py` structure and then get the same result as if I had inserted the text into the `read2.py` code (see below).

**[read2.py](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59562329/10824251)**

```
import re
text = "UUBBBRRLLLBBBDDD"
print( re.sub(r"(.)\1*", lambda x: "{}{}".format( x.group(1), len(x.group())),  text) )
```

But if I run `read.py` I always get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "axios.py", line 5, in <module>
    print( re.sub(r"(.)\1*", lambda x: "{}{}".format( x.group(1), len(x.group())),  text) )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 208, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I understand that I should read `1.txt` as a variable and then read it in the excerpt `print( re.sub(r"(.)\1*", lambda x: "{}{}".format( x.group(1), len(x.group())),  text) )` from `read.py`.

But I don't understand why I didn't read it and it was resulting in an error and I can't read the file directly from `read.py` and get the same result in `read1.py`. I already googled it and haven't found anything involving `module regex`, `read` and `print` together in the same python file as they should work in `read.py`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as typo/can't be reproduced, since the issue was seemingly just caused by using the wrong variable.

Comment: @AMC I still have no experience to be sure if this topic is useful or not open, but I trust the decision of experienced users if it is decided to close this issue.ThanKX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the "text" variable just be "data"? This works:
`print(re.sub(r"(.)\1*", lambda x: "{}{}".format(len(x.group()), x.group(1)), data))`

"text" is a `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>` (i.e. a file-like object) that is read from and then closed, whereas "data" is the variable that holds a reference to a string.

Comment: I had tried this approach and it also worked but I am getting the numeric character "1" at the end of the line of the result. What is the reason?

Comment: Here is the output I get: `U2B3R2L3B3D3`. Could you post your exact output?

Comment: I discovered the cause (though I don't understand) and the cause was that the text in the 1.txt file was surrounded by double quotes at the end and beginning of the string....

Comment: For `U2B3R2L3B3D3`: there are two counts of "U", followed by 3 counts of "B", etc.
For `"1U2B3R2L3B3D3"1`: there is one count of the character `"`, followed by 2 counts of "B", etc. At the end, there is one more count of the character `"`

Comment: Exactly this was the output kkk, I forgot to post the output, forgive me. ThankX @Mr.C, I understood your explanation.